# How do i clear my list after first selection

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I have few checkBoxes and i am storing user decision in a list and then i need to filter the list based on users Decision. The thing is that once i collect the user decision and here  if(UserDecision.Count> 1) i am comparing how many values the user selected if i do it once then its fine but if i filter my articles and then go back to the filter and change the values then its adds on top of it so if i first time selected two options and then i went back and decided i actually want only one the list contains 3 instead of one.

```
public static List<int> UserDecision { get; set; } = new List<int>();

public bool FilterAllItems
{
    set
    {               
        _filterAllItems = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged();
        if (FilterAllItems == true)
        {
            UserDecision.Add(_parentCategoryId = -1);
        }
    }
    get => _filterAllItems;
}

public bool FilterBeginnerItems
{
    set
    {
        _filterBeginnerItems = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged();

        if (_filterBeginnerItems)
        {
            FilterAllItems = false;

            UserDecision.Add(_parentCategoryId = 1);
        }
    }
    get => _filterBeginnerItems;
}

public bool FilterIntermediateItems
{
    set
    {
        _filterIntermediateItems = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged();

        if (_filterIntermediateItems)
        {
            FilterAllItems = false;
            UserDecision.Add(_parentCategoryId = 2);

        }
    }
    get => _filterIntermediateItems;
}


private static List<Article> FindAllArticlesForPurchases(List<Article> allArticles)
{
    foreach(var userDecision in UserDecision)
    {
        if (userDecision != -1)
        {
            if(UserDecision.Count > 1)
            {
                foreach (var categoryGroup in _allUserCategoryGroups)
                {
                    var allGroupCategories = _allCategories.Where(m => m.CategoryGroupId == categoryGroup.Id && UserDecision.Contains(m.CategoryGroupId)).ToList();
                    foreach (var category in allGroupCategories)
                    {
                        var categoryArticles = _allArticlesForPurchase.Where(m => m.CategoryId == category.Id).ToList();

                        allArticles.AddRange(categoryArticles);

                    }

                }
            }    
            else
            {
                allArticles = _allArticlesForPurchase;
            }
        }

        return allArticles;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the `Clear()` method

```
UserDecision.Clear();
```